# control array in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am quite new to Xcode and still do not know a lot of things Xcode can do. I wanna ask if Xcode or Objective-C uses Control Arrays like VB6.

edit: posted question on seperate page.
`How to detect which label or image is selected when they are created dynamically`

Comment: Objective-C is the language, Xcode is the IDE (the editor). AppKit is the framework that deals with user interfaces, which is part of the Cocoa API / program environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Xcode and Obj-C have nothing like control arrays, even though it would be pretty easy to replicate that behavior if you needed to. If you have a specific task you'd like to accomplish, post a question and we may be able to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: You could use a UITableView to emulate a one dimensional control array pretty easily.

Comment: i see, but my application for this part do not need a tableView at all... so sad :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to detect which label or image is selected which are created at runtime, then:

1. Assing tags to the labels/images while creating through code.
2. Write a method which will be invoked when a particular image/label is pressed.
3. Pass the id of the sender when invoking that method.
4. When the invoked method is called,write the code for a particular tag of an image or label (you can use switch case here).

That's it.

Comment: Hi, I have done that approached before I asked the question here. Apparerently both image and label do not have `addTarget:selector:forControlUI` method so that I can pass the id sender. Is it possible to use the `(UIEvent *)event` to extract the sender or which image or label touched?

Comment: What is "assing tags" - I assume this is a typo. Maybe "passing"?

Answer (score 0):

we have control array.... you can declare like `UILabel *lblName[numberOfLabelsYouWant]`

yes but I think what would be useful would be something like: `IBOutlet UILabel* labLicense[20];` which generates a compile time error.

Comment: Ah awesome, I will go try that out. Unfortunately, I do not need a control array anymore. But still, I will look into it and if it works.. I will change my LONG approach using control array. And stack overflow email seems to take 19hrs to inform me there is an answer.. haha